How to stop Catalyst Optimizer from Using Grouping Sets in Spark SQL
I am currently working on a complex Spark SQL query that involves multiple count(distinct()) operations. This leads my job into the Expand stage in the DAG, which proliferates data into several grouping sets, causing the stage to run for extended hours.
I've attempted the following solutions, but to no avail:

Performing a distinct operation first followed by a count in a subquery is not feasible due to a source constraint I have with a custom source.
I've tried replacing distinct(count()) with size(collect_set()), but due to the volume of data, I encountered "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot grow BufferHolder by size 410792240 because the size after growing exceeds size limitation 2147483632".
I attempted to disable the "spark.sql.optimizer.excludedRules", "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ReplaceDistinctWithAggregate" rule, but received an error stating "Optimization rule 'org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ReplaceDistinctWithAggregate' was not excluded from the optimizer because this rule is a non-excludable rule."

Is there any method to instruct the Catalyst Optimizer to refrain from utilizing grouping sets and instead only perform a standard group by operation? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

